# my experience writing an iPhone bluetooth remote control app for personal use only

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, bluetooth

So I am trying to write an app in XCode that only needs to transmit 4 unique signals (up, down, left right) to control motors connected to an arduino. I am not planning on distributing this app or the device it will command, I am simply doing this as a hobbyist project.

I have only just started using xcode but I managed to create a simple 1-page app on my iPhone with 4 buttons that change images as they are pressed/released. But then I ran into some barriers when I started doing research on adding bluetooth functionality to my app.

If I understand correctly from my research the main Bluetooth framework "Core Bluetooth" for xcode is only usable with Bluetooth 4.0 "Low Energy" devices or a very specific subset of Bluetooth Classic devices. I am using a Bluetooth Mate Silver (RN-42); a Bluetooth Classic 2.1 + EDR device, which is suppose to be able to set up data communications with iOS devices as advertised on the following website: http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/RN42

I did manage to connect to this board through my iPhone (confirmed by the iPhone and the connection status LED on the RN-42 breakout board) by setting it up to use the designated profile for iOS devices, and then setting its UUID to one generated by this site: http://bluetooth-pentest.narod.ru/software/bluetooth_class_of_device-service_generator.html

The UUID 0x200400 was generated by selecting Audio for the #Major Service Class and then Audio/Video for #Major Device Class. I was simply trying out different UUID's generated by this site and it just happened to be the first one that caused my bluetooth board to be discovered by my iPhone, so there are probably other UUID's I could use.

I have read that there is another bluetooth toolset for xcode that can be used called Bluetooth Manager Framework but I have read that it requires a Made For iPod (MFi) developer's license which is meant for people that plan on selling/distributing products so obviously I have no desire to pay for that. Is there some way I could use the Bluetooth Manager Framework to send transmit commands to a device that has already been paired / connected through the iPhone settings?

It all seems so hopeless now but I have not given up because I did successfully connect my bluetooth board to my iPhone and I only need to send a single character, or even 2-bit values (at minimum) with each button press/release. I feel like there has to be some way to get my iPhone to transmit something to my board after it is connected. Even if it is by sending fast-forward, pause, play, or rewind commands and using those as motor controlling signals.

After all this, I know for certain that I am getting an Android, but I would still really like to make this work. Any help / advice / confirmation of the hopelessness of this project will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the RN42 is the wrong module for what you want to do.  It can work with iOS with the addition of an MFi licensed chipset or as a keyboard (HID) but that will only send data to your app, it can't be used to receive data from your app.  Something like this - https://www.adafruit.com/products/2479 is better suited.  It can take data sent using Core Bluetooth and deliver it to the serial port on your Arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Paulw11 mentioned,I would suggest you use BLE other than MFi enabled board.
It is easy for you to establish a link and send characters no matter two bytes or more. 
I remembered microchip do have another BLE module which is AT command interface enabled. Please refer http://www.microchip.com/ParamChartSearch/Chart.aspx?branchID=12094 
Their are two options for your work:

1. You just implement a BLE data link channel on you xcode and your arduino, this request you also write code at arduino side to parse the up/down/other event.
2. You can implement a BLE touch or mouse device on your xcode, this need add device descriptor and you may not need programming on arduino(I was not check the arduino side code yet).